# Prove an inequality involving a derivate

Tags: calculus

$y$ is a function of $x$. Specifically,

$$\frac{y(1-y/2)}{(1-y)}=\frac{x(1-sx/2)}{(1-sx)}$$

where $s\in[0,1]$ is a constant and $x\in[0,1]$.

I need to show $\frac{d}{dx}\left(y\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\leq1$.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to show this. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried computing the derivative of both sides of the initial equation?

Comment: Yes I did. After taking the derivatives, I can show  that $\frac{dy}{dx} \le 1$

Comment: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1+\frac{xs(1-xs/2)}{(1-xs)^{2}}}{1+\frac{y(1-y/2)}{(1-y)^{2}}}$$

It can be shown that $$y\geq xs$$

It therefore follows that  $$\frac{dy}{dx}\leq1$$ after some algebra. I think I am correct so far.

Comment: While this is brute force approach, I wonder if the symmetry can be exploited somehow for a simple approach.